# unable to share codes using git

Tags: git, ssh, repository, bitbucket

I'm real real tired on this git error. Which step I'm wrong here

1. My friend create a repository in bitbucket.org and name it test
2. He push codes to the repository by git push and we both see the codes online
3. I do a clone on the project via git clone /myfriend/url/path/test.git
4. I get the codes, initialize git repository and start to work on it
5. I decided to push now on bitbucket so I add a remote url with git remote set-url origin  /myfriend/url/path/test.git, but, When I push, I got the ugly error, please make sure you have access right. So which step I do wrong here?

I have already set up SSH key in bitbucket and also we have set repository into public, not private and in access management, my friend has added my name as admin also. Where I'm wrong guys. Any help please.

Comment: Why are you having to set the origin url?  When i clone a repo, it automatically sets up the "origin" remote for me to the url i cloned from.

Comment: Wait...am i reading this right, that you say like `git clone /the/repo/url`, and then `git init` before you start using it??

Comment: try `git clone` and work on the cloned (and alreday initialized) repo and push. Does this work?

Comment: I have try git clone , but when I check git status on that repo, it says it is not a git repository....???

Comment: @EphraimSwilla if you open up your PuTty (in the notifications area), how many keys do you have? Secondly, is your private key on your machine different from your friend's? if not they need to be unique otherwise Git will complain like #@$!.

Comment: and also check your 'origin' and make sure that the 'Putty Key' field points to wherever you've stored your private key. @EphraimSwilla

Comment: Ok Nice Arty, let me work on it, I never knew about it

Answer (score 0):

> I do a clone on the project via git clone /myfriend/url/path/test.git

From there, you should not initialize a git repo.
You should simply `cd` into `test/` (created by the `git clone`) and start working on it.

If you do `git status` without having changed directory into `test/`, you would get the error message "this isn't a git repo" (because you didn't go into the one you just cloned)

In that repo, `git remote -v` should display one remote `origin`

You can add a second remote:

```
git remote add bitbucket https://accountname@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame
```

(use https at first, with your BitBucket user account)

And you can push to BitBucket:

```
git push bitbucket master
```

---

The [OP Ephraim Swilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1492240/ephraim-swilla) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226230/unable-to-share-codes-using-git/26322842?noredirect=1#comment41418349_26322842) it was an url error:

> I used to add remote url that point to my username instead of friend username which I have cloned, eg:

```
git remote add /bitbucket/:myusername/project.git
```

Comment: Thanks VonC, it works now. It was a very small mistake, I have fixed it

Comment: @EphraimSwilla Great! What was that small mistake?

Comment: Ok @Vonc,I used to add remote url that point to my username instead of friend username which I have cloned eg git remote add /bitbucket/:myusername/project.gi

Comment: @EphraimSwilla ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.